# How to set default value for a core data attribute in xcode 4.0?

Tags: xcode, core-data

I switched from xcode 3.2 to xcode 4.0.In xcode 3.2 there used to be set default value along with attribute name and type.I can't find it in xcode 4.0

Answer (score 33):

Open the Utilities panel (CMD + ALT + 0) (the one from the right side in XCode), then click on the third option (Show the Data Model inspector). You'll find there all you need. You must select the attribute you want to set the default value for.

Comment: Omg I did not know this, has always been doing this in code. This is magic.

Answer (score 0):

The settings of your CoreData attributes are now in the Data Model Inspector in the Utilities (View > Utilities > Show Data Model Inspector).